# Can Freelance Writers be authorized to work in the US?

Tags: visa, employment, usa, freelance

I'm a freelance writer and was looking at applying to more companies. Some of them specify an authorisation to work in the US. I'm a legal resident of India. So what does this mean for me? I don't want to shift to the US, I only want to write for different US based companies. Do I have to set up a corporation so that they can show me as an independent corporation?

Any experience with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "shift to the US"?  If you're not planning to be physically in the US then you won't be working in the US, so you won't need work authorization.

Comment: No but then some jobs specifically list this as a requirement that the applicant should be authorized to work in the US. I am not going to move to the US for one freelance job opportunity, I just would like to be considered, but I'm not sure because they ask for work authorization as one of the conditions.

Comment: If they are willing to hire a freelancer who is out of the country then they don't need to require work authorization.  If they're asking for it, then either they want you to be physically in the US or else they haven't thought it through, or possibly both (i.e., they want you physically in the US because they haven't thought it through).